# onActivityResult is not triggering

Tags: java, android, camera

onActivityResult is not triggering when I click the round button to take a picture in the emulator. Perhaps it's an emulator thing, but I'm hoping it's something else, because I don't, yet, have hardware. I've seen the other posts similar to this (and there are a lot of them), and all have 0 on the rating on the questions and the answers, so no one was able to find a solution.

EDIT: Just a note: If I hit Cancel it does call the onActivityResult method.

```
public void openPhotos(View view) {
    Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(captureIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("Result","TEST");
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris. Are you setting the result on TargetActivity, right? Like: setResult(AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK, intentToReturn); Just asking cause I test here in Emulator and it is working fine...

Comment: are you calling `startActivityForResult()` from fragment? if yes then you should call `super.onActivityResult` in `onActivityResult` of your activity.

Comment: Hey Guilherme, what do you mean set the result. I added this just after Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); setResult(1001, captureIntent); The Log is still not fired.

Comment: user2560050, both of these methods are being called on my main activity. Adding super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data); didn't work.